# ioStat and Awk Output and Format with Megabyte and end of each field

Tags: awk, format, gawk, iostat, megabyte

Would it be possible to add a "Mb" to the end of just MB_r/s and MB_wn/s.   Awk is getting 3 fields and reporting them during the test line to line like below:

example: Format output below:

```
                            ^        ^              
90,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,    1.45,    1890.77,    427911.58
74,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,    1.45,    1890.77,    427911.58
89,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,    1.45,    1890.77,    427911.58
```

---

Command being used I need to have Mb on last 2 reported from awk.

```
iostat -m 3 2 |  grep dm-0 |awk '{a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4}END {print a"\n"b"\n"c"\n"}'
```

I want it to read like below example:

```
                                            ^          ^          
90,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,   1.45Mb,   1890.77Mb,    427911.58
74,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,   1.45Mb,   1890.77Mb,    427911.58
89,    11 Kb,      12 Kb,    101253,   1.45Mb,   1890.77Mb,    427911.58
```

---

Comment: not very sure how your format should look like. Use the `edit` button to prettify it. Also, indicate what is the normal output of `iostat`, we don't know what is the column with "MB_r/s", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out how:

```
iostat -m 3 2 | grep dm-0 |awk '{a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4}END {print a"\n"b"Mb\n"c"Mb\n"}'
```

Worked perfectly :-).

Comment: you don't need grep and a pipe if you're using awk. Just use `iostat -m 3 2 |awk '/dm-0/{a+...`. Can't imagine how that command is producing the output you say you want but as long as you're happy...